# Pandas: ZeroDivisionError occurred even with protection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe I create a new column from the division of two other float columns. So I do that:

```
myFrame['newColumn'] = ( myFrame.floatColumn1 / myFrame.floatColumn2 ).where( 
        ( myFrame.floatColumn1 > 0 ) & ( myFrame.floatColumn2 > 0 ), 0 )
```

So, my code is protected from the division by 0, but even with this protection I got this division error once. The strange thing is that I have millions of rows with 0 in the floatColumn2 and this error never occurred before. I see this error message only one time when I was analyzing logs from the past month.

> ZeroDivisionError: Float division by zero

Am I doing something wrong?

Best Regards,
Luis

Comment: the first part of the code is executed before the `where` clause, so an error should trigger for zerodivision. I think you should do your checks before the division

Comment: You're doing the division before the .where()

Comment: And why this error don`t occured before with the other registers that have 0 in the floatColumn2? I have many, many registers with 0 in the floatColumn2

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which checks for the condition before division:

```
myFrame['newColumn'] = np.where((myFrame.floatColumn1 > 0 ) & ( myFrame.floatColumn2 > 0 ),  myFrame.floatColumn1 / myFrame.floatColumn2, 0)
```

Comment: thank you so much! I will do this. Now I have a last doubt, I have millions of rows with floatColumn2 = 0, this is a valid and default value in my dataframe, why hasn't this problem happened before? Every day thousands of rows have this column with 0